# Swiftt3: Extension to append to Array if not duplicate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I'm trying to write an extension to Array that appends an element to the Array only if the element does not exists in the Array already.

This is my code:

```
extension MutableCollection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    mutating func addObjectIfNew <T: Equatable> (_ item: T)  {
        if !self.contains(item as! Self.Iterator.Element) { 
            self.append(x as! Self.Iterator.Element) // offending line
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> error: value of type 'Self' has no member 'append'

What's the proper way to write such extension?

**Update**: I can't use a Set because I need to perform this operation on an object that needs to be indexed (i.e., Array)

Comment: `append` doesn't exist on `MutableCollection` because not all mutable collections support arbitrary sizes like `Array` does. Make this as an extension on `Array`.

Comment: Also, be careful with this, it's a linear time operation. If you're doing it a lot, it's better to use a set.

Comment: You are already constraining the collection type to equatable, so there is no need to use T: Equatable at your method

Comment: Sets do what you want "out of the box". If you need an ordered collection you can use an `NSOrderedSet` (which I guess is called an `OrderedSet` in Swift 3)

Comment: @LeoDabus This works! Can you please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @LeoDabus howcome your answer doesn't include the `iterator`? Can explain what does the iterator mean actually?

Comment: @Honey Sorry for the late reply on that subject. It used to be required only when extending collection's protocols. When extending Arrays it was not required at that time. Note that this is not a requirement anymore. You can omit it not when extending collection's protocols but I don't know in which Swift version they started allowing it to be omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already constraining the collection elements to equatable, so there is no need to create a new generic equatable type at your method:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func appendIfNotContains(_ element: Element)  {
        if !contains(element) { append(element) }
    }
}
```